# Function wrapper for sqlite3 python and locked database

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, python-asyncio

I wrote a complex python3 application that utilizes sqlite3. The program is asyncio, so I am using aiosqlite and it works pretty well. However, I have several event loops in this program, so I have to create a separate database object for each thread. This works okay, but the issue is that every so often, the database locks and throws `OperationalError`. I have been managing that by catching the error, and that works for the most part. However,  every so often (not too often but once in a while) the database crashes with some operational error. Not entirely sure why as I am handling those errors... But whatever. I was thinking it would be cool if I can do something like this ...

```
async def retry_on_failure(func, args=(), kwargs={}):
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            print('Some error occurs! Waiting a sec ... ')
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

And then wrap my sqlite class functions like:

```
@retry_on_failure
async def select_list(table):
    ...
```

But that doesn't work. I start the program and it is just frozen indefinitely. Is there some way that I can wrap my sqlite calls with a decorator to attempt to run the command again until the database is unlocked? Keep in mind these functions may be called from different event loops, however the object will not be shared between event loops (because that just does not work).

If this isn't possible, then I can do a couple of things like wrap all of my function calls in for loops (which is like .... meh. An ugly solution.) or I was thinking of doing an sqlite command queue where I could append database calls to one queue and then have one master object handle of the actual database calls, returning the results back to whatever thread called it, but that's more work then is probably necessary for a problem like this. Idk, I just think it would cool to use a decorator. Is it possible?

Comment: Try increase the locking timeout?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer .. it turns out that this is not really an sqlite3 problem so much as it was an improperly implemented asyncio function wrapper issue ... This seems to work!

```
from functools import wraps
@wraps
async def retry_on_failure(func, args=(), kwargs={}):
    for _ in range(10):
        print(f'Try {_}')
        try:
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```